# Close button not visible when large image is displayed in lightbox2

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

The close button is not visible when using lightbox2. I have closely review the script and cannot find a cause. Has anyone else had this challenge?

Comment: Please share the script code and the screenshots

Comment: A link to where we can see the issue would be ideal. Otherwise share your page code, browser details, device details, and any steps to recreate.